# Graph import successfully with Neo4j terminal but not in Browser

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, neo4j-browser

I run neo4j-admin to import the database. This is the command

```
set DATA_DIR=D:/Workspace/Research/csv_file

neo4j-admin import --database=foo.db --nodes:Issue=%DATA_DIR%/issues_header.csv,%DATA_DIR%/issues.csv --relationships:LINK=%DATA_DIR%/issue_LINK_issue_header.csv,%DATA_DIR%/issue_LINK_issue.csv --multiline-fields=true
```

After running for a while. It said import successfully

```
IMPORT DONE in 5s 405ms.
Imported:
  1179 nodes
  3025 relationships
  4179 properties
Peak memory usage: 1.03 GB
```

But when I go back to Neo4j Sandbox. Nothing happens. I try to run

```
Match (n) return (n)
```

and nothing returns.

Please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because of so much of data your query might taking time. You can check with the count. Try the query mentioned below to check your data has imported or not

```
Match (n) return count(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Neo4j Sandbox](https://sandbox.neo4j.com/) provides a temporary neo4j environment (for you to play with) **in the cloud**.

But you had imported your data into some other neo4j environment (perhaps on your own machine). You need to use the Browser in *that* environment instead.

Comment: so in my case what is that environment. and how to use it

Comment: On the same machine you did the import, try launching the neo4j Browser in an internet browser like Chrome using the URL `http:://localhost:7474`. You may need to enter the `:use foo.db` command in the neo4j Browser to change to the right database, since your import specified `foo.db` as the database.